# C# string.split() separate string by uppercase

Tags: c#, string, split

I've been using the `Split()` method to split strings. But this work if you set some character for condition in `string.Split()`. Is there any way to split a string when is see `Uppercase`?

Is it possible to get few words from some not separated string like:

```
DeleteSensorFromTemplate
```

And the result string is to be like:

```
Delete Sensor From Template
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`Regex.split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split)

```
string[] split =  Regex.Split(str, @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])");
```

Answer (score 18):

Another way with regex:

```
public static string SplitCamelCase(string input)
{
   return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", " $1", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this hasn't got more upvotes - great use of Trim to handle first and last upper case letters in a very readable, easy to understand bit of code.

Comment: I extended it a bit to deal with acronyms (that could end in lower s), https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBuoy7  see console output for example cases

Answer (score 8):

If you do not like RegEx and you really just want to insert the missing spaces, this will do the job too:

```
public static string InsertSpaceBeforeUpperCase(this string str)
{   
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    char previousChar = char.MinValue; // Unicode '\0'

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(c))
        {
            // If not the first character and previous character is not a space, insert a space before uppercase

            if (sb.Length != 0 && previousChar != ' ')
            {
                sb.Append(' ');
            }           
        }

        sb.Append(c);

        previousChar = c;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had some fun with this one and came up with a function that splits by case, as well as groups together caps (it assumes title case for whatever follows) and digits.

Examples:

Input -> "TodayIUpdated32UPCCodes"

Output ->  "Today I Updated 32 UPC Codes"

Code (please excuse the funky symbols I use)...

```
public string[] SplitByCase(this string s) {
   var ʀ = new List<string>();
   var ᴛ = new StringBuilder();
   var previous = SplitByCaseModes.None;
   foreach(var ɪ in s) {
      SplitByCaseModes mode_ɪ;
      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ɪ.ToString())) {
         mode_ɪ = SplitByCaseModes.WhiteSpace;
      } else if("0123456789".Contains(ɪ)) {
         mode_ɪ = SplitByCaseModes.Digit;
      } else if(ɪ == ɪ.ToString().ToUpper()[0]) {
         mode_ɪ = SplitByCaseModes.UpperCase;
      } else {
         mode_ɪ = SplitByCaseModes.LowerCase;
      }
      if((previous == SplitByCaseModes.None) || (previous == mode_ɪ)) {
         ᴛ.Append(ɪ);
      } else if((previous == SplitByCaseModes.UpperCase) && (mode_ɪ == SplitByCaseModes.LowerCase)) {
         if(ᴛ.Length > 1) {
            ʀ.Add(ᴛ.ToString().Substring(0, ᴛ.Length - 1));
            ᴛ.Remove(0, ᴛ.Length - 1);
         }
         ᴛ.Append(ɪ);
      } else {
         ʀ.Add(ᴛ.ToString());
         ᴛ.Clear();
         ᴛ.Append(ɪ);
      }
      previous = mode_ɪ;
   }
   if(ᴛ.Length != 0) ʀ.Add(ᴛ.ToString());
   return ʀ.ToArray();
}

private enum SplitByCaseModes { None, WhiteSpace, Digit, UpperCase, LowerCase }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another different way if you don't want to be using string builders or RegEx, which are totally acceptable answers. I just want to offer a different solution:

```
string Split(string input)
{
    string result = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(input[i]))
        {
            result += ' ';
        }
    
        result += input[i];
    }
    
    return result.Trim();
}
```

Comment: Actually this is helpful if you're trying to add extra things between like converting `HelloWorldThisIsAPhrase` to `Hello - World, this is a phrase` or something like that. :) Thanks!

Comment: You’re most welcome! Glad it helps you in some way.